# grails: upload files in selected folder

Tags: file, grails, upload, directory

In my Grails application, user needs to upload files in proper folder.
I have implemented (as described [here](http://grails.asia/grails-example-application-simple-document-management-system/)) the system that allows to upload documents in a proper folder, but I need to do some modifications. 
User can upload different kind of files, so I've created folders for each kind of file to upload. So, I need that, after file selection, user can select the folder in which file must be uploaded.
How can I do it?

EDIT:
I think it is needed some clarification. The folder structure that I need to create is the following:

```
- Folder
-- Subfolder
--- Sub-subfolder


- base_folder
-- folderOfUser1
---  folderOfKind1
---  folderOfKind2
---  folderOfKindN

-- folderOfUser2
---  folderOfKind1
---  folderOfKind2
---  folderOfKindN

-- folderOfUserN 
---  folderOfKind1
---  folderOfKind2
---  folderOfKindN
```

So if I cannot use the solution of Sergio because I have "folderOfUserN" that is known only at runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your link, it seems that you need to modify your configuration logic:

```
environments {
    development {
        uploadFolders = [
          pdf : "c:/temp/upload/{username}/pdf",
          png : "c:/temp/upload/{username}/images",
          gif : "c:/temp/upload/{username}/images",
        ]
    }
    test {
        uploadFolder = [...]
    }
    production {
        uploadFolder = [...]
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

When you retrieve the path to the upload replace {username} with the current username. The best place to put this logic is in a service. Assuming that you're using Spring Security:

```
class UploadService {

  static transactional = false //no need to transactions in this service

  static final String PLACEHOLDER = "{username}"

  def grailsApplication

  def springSecurityService

  String getFolderByTpeAndUser(String type) {
    def user = springSecurityService.currentUser
    def path = config[type]?.replace(PLACEHOLDER, user.username)
    return path
  }

  def getConfig() {
    return grailsApplication.config.uploadFolders
  }

}
```

Then you need to add one `g:select` to the view showing this options, and change `DocumentController` to reflect the option selected by the user.

Comment: it is a good answer but not fit perfectly my issue. I give some clarification editing my post above. Thanks

Comment: folderOfUser is his username? Just handle it in the controller.

Comment: folderOfUser is his username. How to handle it in the controller if I have uploadFolders as you suggest? the correct folder must be "c:/temp/upload/username/pdf" and so on. What do you suggest to do?

Comment: See my edit, you can use some "key" that will be replaced by the runtime value.

Comment: The only problem that I have is about "type": if I use pdf, png or gif I have an exception "no such property"

Comment: Solved using double quotes!

Comment: Is there any way to make path relatives?